# How do you update user document on mongoDB, NodeJs and Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

How do you update user document on mongoDB, NodeJs and Express? Would it be another 'post' form or is it simply just updating?

My  `storeUser.js` file:

```
const User = require('../models/User') 
const path = require('path')
module.exports = (req, res) => {
    let image = req.files.image;
    image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname,'..','public/img',image.name), async (error) => {
        await User.create({
            ...req.body,
            image: '/public/img/' + image.name
        })
        res.redirect('/')
    })
}
```

My `index.js` file::

```
const express = require('express')
const app =  new express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const ejs = require('ejs')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const userSignUpController = require('./controllers/newUser')
const homeController = require('./controllers/home')
const storeUserController = require('./controllers/storeUser')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
const loginController = require('./controllers/login')
const loginUserController = require('./controllers/loginUser')
const expressSession = require('express-session')
const redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware = require('./middleware/redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware')
const userProfileController = require('./controllers/userprofile')
const logoutController = require('./controllers/logout')
const clubProfileController = require('./controllers/clubProfile')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/club_archive', {useNewUrlParser:true})

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(fileUpload())
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}))


app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')


app.listen(3000, 
    console.log("listening on port 3000")
)

global.loggedIn = null
app.use("*", (req, res, next) => {
    loggedIn = req.session.userId;
    next()
})
app.get('/', homeController)
app.get('/signup',redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware,userSignUpController)
app.post('/adduser',redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, storeUserController)
app.get('/login',redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, loginController)
app.post('/userlogin',redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, loginUserController)
app.get('/userprofile', userProfileController)
app.get('/userlogout',logoutController)
app.get('/clubprofile',clubProfileController )
```

These are two files storeUser.js is a post form that adds a user to the database, and index.js handles all of the routes and packages. So the main question is how do I update a user profile in javascript, do I need to create a new file and form? or is it a simple if statement?

Comment: The question back to you is what do you like the most? Everyone has their own style in writing code. So, from me, it's better to separate them, so that when you have a problem, you can easily find it. Besides it doesn't hurt you learn from small things, because for large-scale applications, it's good if separated. But it's back to you, what you like the most.

Comment: i would prefer to use a separate file. I couldn't find any useful documentation on how to update a specific user document for mongo using javascript.